# Meteor - Transfer users to another replica server if one server goes down

Tags: meteor

I am using Meteor server `v1.8.`

I want to create a backup server.

If Main server goes down, users should automatically transferred to a backup server, to avoid any down time.

How can I achieve such behaviour.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should read abount MongoDB [clusters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/) and [replication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/)

Comment: @Jankapunkt actually I am talking about the server management, if main server app crashed, it should automatically transfer the users to a backup server, with same dns

Comment: Did my answer helped you with your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use process spawning tools like [Phusion Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) to make your application failsafe. If you app crashes, Passenger restarts it immediately.

Some resources on that:

https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Phusion-Passenger:-Meteor-tutorial

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/docs/tutorials/installation/meteor/

Or use some [container orchestration](https://www.docker.com/products/orchestration) and make your app available on more than one machines. If one instance fails, your app should still be available.

**In both cases:** install your mongodb **on a separate server**. This is also why you need to define the `MONGO_URL` environment variable on your Meteor deployment, so your app process is separated from the Database process.

In such a setup you won't need to "submit" data on failure to a separate server, which I think might even not be a realistic approach in a production environment.

Comment: I will give it a try for sure. Thanks